# Android: wait for vibrator to finish

Tags: android, conditional-statements, wait, android-vibration

Let's say I have async tasks that when finished, lock the vibrator and send it a pattern. In a nutshell, that's the kind of code I'm dealing with:

```
lock(vib);
vib.vibrate(pattern);
release(vib);
return;
```

The problem is, the vibration starts and just immediately stops due to the task's returning and I could use some help in changing that.

I have tried

```
lock(vib);

long duration = getDuration(pattern);

vib.vibrate(pattern);

synchronized(this){
    try {
        wait(duration);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        ...
    }
}

release(vib);
return;
```

but that doesn't seem to actually do anything.

Since I have not found a way to determine whether or not the phone is currently vibrating, any suggestions on how I should best resolve the issue?

Comment: What exactly are you doing with those lock, release calls?

Comment: I just set an atomicboolean to true/false, really.

lock is "while(!myBool.compareAndSet(false, true));"

release is "if(!myBool.compareAndSet(true, false)) {...}" with some error handling if it fails.

Comment: Are you finishing the app after the task ends? Where do you have this code in the AsyncTask(onPostExecute())?

Comment: The method is in an auxiliary object. The task invokes the method before it returns from its "doInBackground(...)"

Comment: Almost forgot: No, I'm not finishing the app after the task ends.